# How to delete zeroes in the upper triangular part of a matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have a matrix 'A' with shape(68,68) and its upper triangle has only zeroes in it. The lower triangle has the values I'm interested in. For instance:

```
>>> A
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

How can I obtain a matrix 'B' with no values in the upper triangle, like this:

```
>>> B
array([[  ,   ,  ],
       [ 1,   ,  ],
       [ 2,  3,  ],
       [ 4,  5, 6]])
```

Comment: I didn't know numpy allowed for empty matrix entries at all. Is it possible to set a single entry to be empty?

Comment: Numpy doesn't allow empty elements in a matrix. But if you want all values that are not 0 you can just use `numpy.extract` or `numpy.nonzero()` function to remove all 0 values.

Comment: "How can I obtain a matrix 'B' with no values in the upper triangle" There is **no such thing** as an element of a Numpy array "not having a value". Furthermore, there would be no practical way to use such a result.

Comment: What are you *doing* with `B` that can't just ignore the upper-triangular entries?

Comment: Ok, @JacobValdez. Maybe that's why I'm not being able to delete the entries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a representation for "no value" in numpy, at least not in the way that you explained.

The closest you can get is probably [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan), which is a commonly-used representation of "not a number".

`np.nan` is treated as a number in the sense that it doesn't break any code that tries to work mathematically with it, but it's not considered to be zero either because any operation done with it results in a `np.nan`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

>>> 0 + 10  
# output: 10

>>> np.nan + 10
# output: nan
```

In your case, replacing the upper triangular part of `A` with `np.nan` effectively means "ignore this part in any operations done with `A`".

As to *how* to replace the values with `np.nan`s, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 1,  0,  0],
    [ 2,  3,  0],
    [ 4,  5,  6],
])

A = A.astype(float)
A[A == 0] = np.nan

print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[nan nan nan]
 [ 1. nan nan]
 [ 2.  3. nan]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]]
```

Note that we had to convert `A` from an integer matrix to a float matrix, since `np.nan`s are technically considered to be floats.